# Controlling a servo without the servo library

Tags: servo, pwm, analog

I am trying to control a servo without the "Servo.h" library.I am sending using `analogWrite()` some values to the servo.I know the servo takes input a continuous time signal however I dont know the necessary frequency of that signal so I am not producing any sensible movement.What else should I consider when trying to control the servo using `analogWrite()`s?

Comment: `analogWrite()` is not suitable for driving servos. What is your issue with the Servo library?

Comment: `I dont know the necessary frequency of that signal` ... it is not the frequency that is critical ... it is the pulse width that is critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `digitalWrite()` and `delayMicroseconds()`.

A servo is driven by a pulse. The pulse is between 1 ms (0°) over 1.5 ms (90°) to 2 ms (180°), followed by a pause that makes the total duration of a cycle 20 ms.

The 20 ms correspond to a 50 Hz signal. `analogWrite()` uses frequencies from 490 to 1000 Hz (depending on your hardware), which is why that won't work unless you figure out how to change the frequency.